# RxJS indeterminate master details recursive observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have been struggling to get nested recursive observable chains right. The requirement is to right a utility that would fetch parent-child (master-detail) records based on a configuration similar to the following.

```js
  "ParentEntity": {
    "table": "table_master",              
    "details": {
      "detail1": {
        "table": "tbl_detail1"
      },
      "detail2": {
        "table": "tbl_detail2"
            "details": {
                "detail21": { 
                "table": "tbl_detail21"
              }
            }
      },
      "detail3": {
        "table": "tbl_detail3"
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the sample scenario code.

```js
function trace(output) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(output));
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
  element = document.getElementById("result");
  element.appendChild(newDiv);
}

var propertiesWithDetails = {
  "b": "b",
  "d": "d"
};

var firstLevelResultList = [{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "c": "c",
  "d": "d"
}, {
  "a": "a1",
  "b": "b1",
  "c": "c1",
  "d": "d1"
}];


function getResultObservable(prop) { // just creating some dummy details record.

  return Rx.Observable.of({
    "details": prop
  }).delay(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
}


function runCodeWithDo() {
  Rx.Observable.of(firstLevelResultList).do(result => {
    result.forEach(record => {
      Object.keys(propertiesWithDetails).map((prop) => {

        getResultObservable(prop).do(childData => {

          record[prop] = childData;
        })
      })

    });
  }).subscribe(output => {

    trace(output);
  });

}


function runCodeWithFlatMapAndForkJoin() { //this is recursive in actual code

  return Rx.Observable.of(firstLevelResultList).flatMap(result => {

    if (result != null && result.length > 0 && propertiesWithDetails != null) {
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { //tried forkJoin around this, ended up in some error
        let record = result[i];
        return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
          Object.keys(propertiesWithDetails).map((prop) => {
            return getResultObservable(prop).map(childData => {
              record[prop] = childData;
            })
          })
        ).map((res) => {
          return record
        })

      }
    } else return Rx.Observable.of(result);
  });

}

var expectedResult = [{
  "a": "a",
  "b": {
    "details": "b"
  },
  "c": "c",
  "d": {
    "details": "d"
  }
}, {
  "a": "a1",
  "b": {
    "details": "b"
  },
  "c": "c1",
  "d": {
    "details": "d"
  }
}];

trace("expected result is: " + JSON.stringify(expectedResult));
trace("...........");
runCodeWithDo();

trace(" only the first level records listed, detail data not fetched ");
trace(".................");
runCodeWithFlatMapAndForkJoin().subscribe(result => {
  trace("...............");
  trace(result);
  trace(" only one of the parents records returned ! ");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Indeterminate recursive child observables (parent child) </title>
  <meta name="description" content="recursive child observables">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
</head>

<body>
  <p> Indeterminate recursive child observables </p>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically the utility executes select * from  (sqlite) and constructs the output data structure based on the hierarchy in the configuration. The executeSql statements executions are wrapped in an observable (i.e. result is an observable containing an array).
I tried my best using Observable.flatMap, forkJoin, do, switchMap etc. But failed to get it right.

Appreciate any help to solve this.

RxJS version: 5.4.2
The  utility is being used in an ionic 3/Angular 4 mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

The following logic resolved the issue

```
 function runCodeWithNestedForkJoins() {

    return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {   
        Rx.Observable.of(firstLevelResultList).subscribe(result => {            
            if(result != null && result.length > 0 &&  propertiesWithDetails != null) {             
                let recordObservable = []; // for the records in 'result'               
                result.forEach( record => {             
                    recordObservable.push( Rx.Observable.create(obs => {                        
                        Rx.Observable.forkJoin( //for the detail objects
                            Object.keys(propertiesWithDetails).map((prop) => {                                  
                                return getResultObservable(prop).map(detailData => {                    
                                    record[prop] = detailData; // detail object is being set in the parent record   
                                })
                            }
                            )
                        ).subscribe((res) => {
                            //all the details objects are fetched, completing the observable
                            obs.next(res);
                            obs.complete();
                        })
                    })
                    );

                })              
                // execute parent record observables in a forkjoin          
                Rx.Observable.forkJoin(recordObservable).subscribe(res => { // details objects are already set in the parent record in the 'map' operator above
                        observer.next(result);//yes, not 'res'
                        observer.complete();
                })              
            }
            else {
                // no details to be fetched, just return the parent result
                observer.next(result);
                observer.complete();            
            }
        }); 
    }); 
 }
```

If you know of any other better way of achieving this, please post your answer